# Next JS / React: Cloudinary error: Cannot add property __, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to load media (image and videos) from Cloudinary in a NextJS App, I'm following the [API documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration#landingpage) and my code is basically the same as the examples in the docs.

my code:

```
import { Cloudinary } from "@cloudinary/url-gen";
import { AdvancedImage as Image } from "@cloudinary/react";

interface CloudinaryMediaProps {
  id?: string;
}

export const CloudinaryMedia: FC<CloudinaryMediaProps> = () => {
  const myCld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
      cloudName: "cloudinary-workspace",
    },
  });

  const myImage = myCld.image("image");

  return (
    <div>
      <Image cldImg={myImage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

With this simple example, I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot add property __, object is not extensible
```

[Cloudinary error: Cannot add property __, object is not extensible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFcke.png)

Does someone know how can I resolve this error? Or if I'm missing something?

Comment: This looks identical to the docs, like you said, have you tried going back to a previos version incase something broke in a recent version? If that doesn't resolve it I would add an issue to their github for this library

Comment: Hi @OlliePugh, thanks for answering!
I tried, I back @cloudinary/url-gen and @cloudinary/react version, to:
~1.7.0 / ~1.3.0  
~1.6.0 / ~1.2.0 
~1.5.0 / ~1.1.0 

The same error happened in all versions, I'm wondering if maybe it's something related to the Next Js app.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Next.js really, but, dont alias `AdvancedImage` to `Image` incase next has some sort of global imported image component? as in the example they use it as `AdvancedImage` see if that gives you any luck

Comment: I tried with the alias to try to resolve the error, but the same happens with no alias, using `<AdvancedImage cldImg={myImage} />` directly. But thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Yeah thats all I can think of unfortunatley, have you tried with a brand new plain react project just to see if it is infact your next setup?

Answer (score 0):

The following Cloudinary packages have to be installed in your environment:

- @cloudinary/url-gen
- @cloudinary/react

See here for a working sample code: https://replit.com/@ecptest/AdvanceImageTest#pages/cldfrontendsdk.tsx

```
import { Cloudinary } from "@cloudinary/url-gen";
import { AdvancedImage as Image } from "@cloudinary/react";

interface CloudinaryMediaProps {
  id?: string;
}

export const CloudinaryMedia: React.FC<CloudinaryMediaProps> = () => {
  const myCld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
      cloudName: "demo",
    },
  });

  const myImage = myCld.image("sample");
  myImage.format("jpg");

  return (
    <div>
      <Image cldImg={myImage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, you will need to have to sign up for an account with Cloudinary (i.e.,
for the parameter `cloudName = <cloudinary_cloud_name>`).

Additionally, it is also necessary to [use the public_id](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_glossary#public_id) of the asset that is already available in your Media Library account, which is the unique identifier of the asset and is either specified when uploading the asset to your Cloudinary account or automatically assigned by Cloudinary (see Upload images for more details on the various options for specifying the public ID). It can also be divided into folders for more structured delivery URLs, which can be done by separating the elements with slashes (`/`).

```
const myImage = myCld.image("<public_id>");
```